# How to pass arrays and their contents from a controller to a view

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I am a novice in Yii and I have a problem passing arrays from an action in a controller to a view so that I can read contents of the arrays in the view itself.

My controller:

```
public function actionReportAllWeeks()
{
    $user = YumUser::getById(Yii::app()->user->id);
    $format = 'Y-m-d';
    $clients = Client::model()->findAll();
    $UNI = array();$NPP = array();$DAN = array();$McC = array();$CAS = array();$LAC = array();
    foreach ($clients as $client) {
        $project_count = 0;
        $projects = Project::model()->findAll(array('condition'=>'client_id='.$client->id));
        for ($i=1; $i < 30; $i++) { 
            foreach ($projects as $project) {
                $date_created = $project->created;
                $createdDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date_created);
                $week_num = $createdDate->format('W');
                if ($client->shortname == 'UNI') {
                    if ($week_num == $i) {
                        $UNI[$i]++;
                    }
                }
                elseif ($client->shortname == 'NPP') {
                    if ($week_num == $i) {
                        $NPP[$i]++;
                    }
                }
                elseif ($client->shortname == 'DAN') {
                    if ($week_num == $i) {
                        $DAN[$i]++;
                    }
                }
                elseif ($client->shortname == 'McC') {
                    if ($week_num == $i) {
                        $McC[$i]++;
                    }
                }
                elseif ($client->shortname == 'CAS') {
                    if ($week_num == $i) {
                        $CAS[$i]++;
                    }
                }
                elseif ($client->shortname == '') {
                    if ($week_num == $i) {
                        $LAC[$i]++;
                    }
                }                       
            }
        }
    }

    $this->render('client/client', array('clients'=>$clients, 'UNI'=>$UNI, 'NPP'=>$NPP, 'DAN'=>$DAN, 'McC'=>$McC, 'CAS'=>$CAS, 'LAC'=>$LAC));
}
```

My View:

```
<table class="table table-striped table table-bordered" style="width:95%">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Projects</th>
      <?php for ($i=1; $i < 52; $i++):?>
        <td style="text-align:center">Week <?php echo $i; ?></td>
      <?php endfor; ?>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($clients as $client): ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $client->name; ?></td>
    <?php for ($i=1; $i < 52; $i++):?>
      <td style="text-align:center">/*should echo some values from array*/</td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </tr>     
<?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
```

When i try to read elements from any array, i get "Undefined offset 1" error.

Comment: Are you sure your array is well populated? For example if you do a `var_dump($clients);` before calling the `render` does it display a good array?

Comment: And instead of `/*should echo some values from array*/` show us the code that u put here!

Comment: you are using $i = 1 to 52, however the /*should echo some values from array*/ part can contain something that uses the wrong array.

Comment: It seems like you could accomplish this in SQL joing client and projects, with a group by on your date using WEEKOFYEAR and client.shortname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself implies that your array doesn't have a value at index 1.  It appears that you've jumped to a conclusion that the error is in your view and not your controller.

Your error is probably happening before the view as looking at your controller code, in each of your conditionals, you have code similar to:

```
$someArray[$i]++;
```

All of these will error as `$someArray[$i]` is undefined; all your arrays are empty to start.

I'd suggest you populate your arrays to start using [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php), e.g.:

```
$NPP = array_fill(1,52,0);
```

*Note that this ignores the fact that your index in your controller is from 1 to 30, while in your view is 1 to 52.*

For future reference, make sure to include the full error message you see, which should include a file and line number.  I'm guessing if you looked at the error, it would have pointed to one of the incrementing lines in your controller, not your view.